# Install pip on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When I try to install the package zeros it shows this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement zeros (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for zeros
```

I have the pip 21.1.2 version.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is `zeros` module for? Link ?

Comment: There is no package zeros AFAICT https://pypi.org/search/?q=zeros

Comment: Your error clearly specifies that it cannot get the package-name you told to install. ```zeros``` module is not there. What do you want ```zeros``` for? ```pip install zero``` does this satisfy your requirement

Comment: That is what I am asking how to i install the version of pip that supports zero.

Comment: I tried to install zeros to use in numpy to get 2D matrix but then I got suggestion to install zero instead of zeros but then too I am unable to use it after successfully downloading zero instead of zeros and I am unable to understand the difference between the two. Plz help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `pip install zero` if this is what you are looking for. And your python version is fine. Works on my system